# How to select Matrix elements with a filter-matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 2 martices of the same size. The first contains values and the second only elements of 0 and 1 (like boolean). I now want all elements of my first Matrix stored in an array where the second Matrix has a 1 at the same index.

Maybe an example makes that clear:

Matrix 1:

a b c

d e f

g h i

Matrix 2:

0 1 1

1 0 0

0 0 1

output:
[b c d i]

I think this will work in two  steps, but i cant get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will need two steps indeed.

```
%# transpose Matrix 1 because Matlab iterates by row first
matrix_1 = matrix_1';

%# read values (transpose M2 as well)
%# also transpose the result to get a row-vector
output = matrix_1(matrix_2')';
```

Note that this indexing operation only works if `matrix_2` is logical. If it isn't, cast it by writing `logical(matrix_2)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If your arrays are `a` and `b`, with `b` the mask array, try

```
a(find(b))
```

This won't produce the output in the order in your question.  If order is important resort to @Jonas' approach.

Comment: You may want to transpose first to get the order of entries right.

Comment: Assuming things like order are not important and `b` is (cast as) `logical`, it even simplifies to `a(b)`.